# Cycle video display ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, merge, video-processing, cycle

I'm new to ffmpeg so I've been struggling to get this code to work so I thought I'd reach out to the community.
Essentially, I was wondering how I could write an ffmpeg command that switches between displaying a video from the inputs I provide every 10 seconds. Ideally, there would be a crossfade transition when switching between videos.
As an example, let's say I have 3 inputs (v1, v2, v3). Say each video is of a duration of 1 minute. The output video would look something like this:

v1(0-10s) -> v2(10-20s) -> v3(20-30s) -> v1(30-40s) -> v2(40-50s) -> v3(50-60s) where the arrows would be crossfade transitions.
Any advice or input you could provide on how I could start on something like this would be a huge help.

Best,
Lucas

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as explained by the ffmpeg tag: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

xfade:

```
ffmpeg \
-ss  0 -to 10.2 -i "1.mkv" \
-ss 10 -to 20.2 -i "2.mkv" \
-ss 20 -to 30.2 -i "3.mkv" \
-ss 30 -to 40.2 -i "1.mkv" \
-ss 40 -to 50.2 -i "2.mkv" \
-ss 50 -to 60.2 -i "3.mkv" \
-filter_complex "
[0:0][1:0]xfade=transition=pixelize:duration=0.2:offset=10[xxx];
[xxx][2:0]xfade=transition=pixelize:duration=0.2:offset=20[xxx];
[xxx][3:0]xfade=transition=pixelize:duration=0.2:offset=30[xxx];
[xxx][4:0]xfade=transition=pixelize:duration=0.2:offset=40[xxx];
[xxx][5:0]xfade=transition=pixelize:duration=0.2:offset=50;
" output.mp4
```